# Runnable is getting called continuously in milliseconds when I set postDelayed time for more than 25 days

Tags: android, runnable

Runnable is getting called continuously in milliseconds when I set postDelayed interval for more than 25 days. It is not calling the runnable after 25 days but it gets called after every 10 milliseconds due to which the application crashes. I am doing network operation in this runnable. Is there any max limit for post delayed time?

```
mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 600 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: You have to at least put some code for us to look at.

Comment: I would recommend you to use JobScheduler https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler instead of runnable

Comment: You can use WorkManger for that https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: @Farhood ET mHandler.postDelayed(runnable,
      600 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

Comment: @Reena, thank you, your solution is working but I need to know the root cause of runnable getting called every 10 milliseconds.

Comment: @Chandan, thank you, your solution is working but I need to know the root cause of runnable getting called every 10 milliseconds

Comment: You need to paste your code so that we can look into it

Answer (score 3):

Your math is in 32-bit signed integers and there's an overflow.

`600 * 60 * 60 * 1000` is `0x80befc00` which is a negative integer and stays negative when promoted to long. Calling `postDelayed()` with a negative delay means "immediately" which with default `Handler` settings means next vsync (every 16ms with 60Hz refresh rate).

To fix the math, change one of the operands to long to work with 64-bit integers, e.g. `600 * 60 * 60 * 1000L`.

Anyway, `Handler#postDelayed()` is not really suited for such long-running tasks. Consider e.g. [`WorkManager`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation